# Display list of distinct book names from LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a view that I want to display a DISTINCT list of book names.  My problem is I am getting ...GenericList is not assignable to model type ...

If I remove the distinct part of my LINQ statement, I get all of the books, but they include duplicates.  I just want a distinct list.  Thanks

Here is what I have:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Chapters(string book)
    {
        var chapter = (from b in Bible.Books
                       where b.Name == book
            select b.Name);
        return View(chapter);
    }

    @model IEnumerable<BibleApp.Models.Book>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "All Books";
}

<h2>All</h2>

<p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    @foreach (var book in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="">@Html.DisplayFor(x => book.Name)</a></li>
    }
</ul>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your current Model, which expects a collection of `Book` instead of a collection of string then use `GroupBy` to group on `Book`'s Name property and then get a `First` member from that group like:

```
 var chapter = Bible.Books
                   .GroupBy(b=> b.Name)
                   .Select(grp=> grp.First());

 return View(chapter);
```

This will give you a collection of `Book` items based on distinct `Name`.

If you could modify your `View` to accept a Model of `IEnumerable<string>` then you can use your existing code, *(that should be the acceptable approach if you are only interested in Book's Name and not other properties)*

```
 var chapter = (from b in Bible.Books
                where b.Name == book
                select b.Name).Distinct();
 return View(chapter);
```

Or with a method syntax:

```
var chapter = Bibile.Books.Select(b=> b.Name).Distinct();
```

Comment: I had to change your query to  var chapter = Bible.Books
                   .GroupBy(b=> b.Name)
                   .Select(grp=> grp.FirstOrDefault()); and it worked.  Thank you so much

Comment: @C.Coggins, you are welcome, Not really sure why `First` didn't work for you. Each group must have atleast a single item.